# XML Special Characters in oozie workflow properties

Tags: hadoop, oozie

This is a snippet of my oozie workflow.xml

```
<property>
   <name>statement</name>                   
   <value>${statement}</value>
</property>
```

The statement may contain characters such as '>', '<' etc. When statement contains '>' (without encoding), my job  runs successfully however if the statement contains '<', job fails with error "JA007: Error on line : The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup"

For example
case a: statement = "x>3;y>4" (No errors)
case b: statement = "x>3;y<4" (JA007)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the underlying issue. SAXBuilder can parse this piece of line well
"x>2"

but fails with an exception for following line
"x<2"

Both ">" , "<" are xml special characters and ideally, behavior should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

The SAX parser is reading the left bracket as the start of a child element tag, while the right bracket signals the end of an element tag. If the parser isn't currently inside an element tag then the right bracket is probably considered legal, and accepted.

If you haven't already resolved this, you want to define statement as follows to XML escape the left and right brackets:

```
statement=x&gt;3;y&lt;4
```

This will work fine in a properties file, but if you're passing variables from the command line using the `-Dkey=value` notation, then you'll need to wrap the argument in quotes to avoid the ampersands being wrongly interpreted by the shell:

```
"-Dstatement=x&gt;3;y&lt;4"
```